# How to manage DB connection in Scala using functional programming style?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, database-connection

I have a piece of Scala code using DB connection:

```
def getAllProviderCodes()(implicit conf : Configuration) : List[String] = {
  var conn: java.sql.Connection = null
  try {
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DBInfo.dbUrl(conf), DBInfo.dbUserName(conf), DBInfo.dbPassword(conf))
    return ResultSetIterator.create(
              conn.prepareStatement("SELECT pcode FROM providers").executeQuery()
           ){_.getString("pcode")}.toList
  } catch {
    case e: Exception =>
      logger.warn("Something went wrong with creating the connection: " + e.getStackTrace)
  } finally {
    if (conn != null) {
      conn.close()
    }
  }
  List()
}
```

It's very OOP-Java-like style, so I'd like to know is there a way to write it in more functional way? I tried to succeed in applying [Try](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/Try.html) monad, but failed: my biggest concern is that we have state here, as well as `finally` block. Maybe there's some kind of pattern for such cases?

Thank you in advance.

**UPD:** Here's the example from [here](https://scalerablog.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/scalera-tip-why-scala-util-try-doesnt-have-finally-clause/) of what IMHO the solution will look like:

```
val connection = database.getConnection()
val data: Seq[Data] = Try{
  val results = connection.query("select whatever")
  results.map(convertToWhatIneed)
} recover {
  case t: Throwable => 
    Seq.empty[Data]
} get
connection.close()
```

But as I've mentioned in the comment, I have to close the connection, then I have to place all the things regarding to connection inside Try to keep it pure... and then I  to the variant with "try-catch-finally" inside Try block.

Comment: Can you post your failing code using `scala.util.Try` so we can help you see where you went wrong?

Comment: @JamesWhiteley actually I don't have example of failing code, since I was just figuring out how it can be implemented. I thought it should be something similar to https://scalerablog.wordpress.com/2016/05/16/scalera-tip-why-scala-util-try-doesnt-have-finally-clause/
But I'm stuck when I have to close the connection, then understand that all the things regarding to connection should be placed inside Try... and then return to the variant with "try-catch-finally", only inside Try block :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never played around with the Java SQL Connection library so the syntax of my answer has been written as pseudocode, but if I understand your question correctly here is how I would implement what you have done:

```
def getAllProviderCodes()(implicit conf : Configuration): List[String] = {
  val conn: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(???) // replace ??? with parameters

  val result: List[String] = Try {
    ??? // ResultSetIterator stuff
  } match {
    case Success(output) => output // or whatever .toList thing
    case Failure(_) => List.empty // add logging here
  }

  if(conn != null) conn.close()
  result // will be whatever List you make (or an empty List if Try fails)
}
```

Instead of a Java-like `try-catch-finally` block, one Scala-like way of doing things would be to put the stuff which could explode in a `Try` block and assigning the response to a value using `case Success(out)` and `case Failure(ex)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just pull the connection outside of the try:

```
 val conn = getConnection()
 try {
    doStuff(conn)
 } finally { 
    conn.close
 }
```

If you want the result of whole thing to be a `Try`, just wrap it into a Try:

```
 def doDBStuff = Try {
   val conn = getConnection()
   try {
    doStuff(conn)
   } finally { 
    conn.close
   }
 }
```

Or with a bit less nesting (but this will throw connection exceptions):

```
 def doDBStuff = {
   val conn = getConnection()
   val result = Try { doStuff(conn) }
   conn.close
   result
 }
```