# Memory leak with JDBC / SQLite

Tags: java, scala, sqlite, jdbc, memory-leaks

I have some code which accesses a SQLite database using JDBC.

I've noticed that every time a query is made, the memory usage increases - and it does not go down, even after the connection is closed.

Here's what I'm doing:

1) Closing the `PreparedStatement`

2) Closing the `ResultSet`

3) Closing the connection

Here's a screenshot of the heapdump analysis:

[image: heap dump screenshot]

It shows a lot of `java.lang.ref.Finalizer` and a lot of `PreparedStatement` and `ResultSet` objects.

Here's the code (its in scala but should be easily comparable to java):

```
val conn: Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url)


// Gets strings by a query like SELECT .. WHERE foo = ?
def getStringsByQuery(query: String, param: String, field: String):Seq[String] = {

    val st = conn.prepareStatement(query)
    st.setString(1, param) //value of foo = ?
    st.setFetchSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    st.setMaxRows(Integer.MAX_VALUE)

    //Holder of results
    var results = collection.mutable.Seq.empty[String]

    val rs: ResultSet = st.executeQuery()

    //add results to holder
    while (rs.next())
      results :+= rs.getString(field)

    rs.close() //closing ResultSet
    st.close() //closing PreparedStatement
    results
  }
```

Here's the test I wrote to test this:

```
test("detect memory leak") {

    log.info("Starting in 10 sec")
    Thread.sleep(10.seconds.toMillis)

    //Calls a method over and over to see if there's a memory leak or not..
    (1 to 1000).par.foreach(i => {
      val randomWord = getRandomWord() //this produces a random word
      val sql = "SELECT foo FROM myTable where bar = ?"
      val results = getStringsByQuery(sql, randomWord, "bar")
    })

    conn.close() //close the connection
    log.info("Closed conn, closing in 30 sec")

    Thread.sleep(1.minutes.toMillis)
  }
```

When I run the test - the memory usage steadily increases from 24.6 GB to 33 gb and never goes down (even though ResultSet + PreparedStatement are being closed), and even at the end when the conn is closed and thread sleeps for 1 min - the memory usage still doesn't go down.

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Close connection every iteration

Comment: No difference @user7294900

Comment: I also updated to the latest version of SQLite Driver - no difference

Comment: Did you tried adding try clause ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51263449/how-to-manage-db-connection-in-scala-using-functional-programming-style

Comment: @user7294900 I believe that shouldn't be necessary in this case because the resources are being closed directly without any exception occurring

Comment: I'd be looking into st.setFetchSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE) and the reasoning why it is being set to  Integer.MAX_VALUE ?

Comment: @mkane i want it to return all results in the same query without multiple queries - since its all in a local Sqlite file. I just tested setting fetch size to 1k. It causes memory to sometimes go down and not just up - but overall, it still ends up going up substantially with each iteration

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I resolved this issue by porting my Sqlite datasets to CQEngine. Couldn't be happier.

Answer (score 5):

We run sqlite-jdbc in a production environment and we noticed similar behavior when inspecting heap dumps.

These objects are only on the heap because they haven't yet been run through the garbage collector.  In the sense of https://blog.nelhage.com/post/three-kinds-of-leaks/ this is a "type 2 memory leak", in that the objects have been allocated and are living a bit longer than you expect.

The problem this caused for us is machines would retain memory on the Java heap for unexpectedly long periods of time, running into memory pressure during peak request times.  We did a few different things to ensure that these objects would be collected more frequently.

- Decrease overall Java heap size.  This ensures that the garbage collector sees more of a need to clean up these objects.  Our workload is very intense on SQLite, so it's better for machine memory to go to the off-heap memory through JNI rather than being allocated on the Java heap.
- Tune the G1GC garbage collector to allocate more of the heap for newgen since these objects are usually very short-lived. (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html)
- Increase our garbage collector logging and run them through a service like GCEasy (https://gceasy.io/) to understand exactly what types of garbage collector runs were happening for further tuning.

These may not match your use case but these are some options you can consider depending on what you're running into.

Comment: Hey tildedave - were you also using JDBC to access SQLite? Did you also see PreparedStatements/ResultSets not being GC'd? Were they eventually being GC'd - if so, after around how long?

Comment: Yeah, we run sqlite-jdbc using the xerial-sqlite library basically like in your question.    The services run for days or weeks at a time.  (Edited the answer to be a bit more clear.)  I'm not certain what timescale the objects will be collected on.  It does depend on how you've configured the garbage collector, so if you're seeing issues (beyond your test case) that's a place you can start looking.

Comment: Are you able to share your GC settings which you've ended up using ?

Comment: So the GC settings we have are pretty specific to our app and I'm not sure they're generally useful.  The main benefit we got was in reducing our heap size which is where I'd start if you're seeing memory issues in your application.  We also currently override InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent (GC more frequently), G1OldCSetRegionThresholdPercent (GC more frequently), G1MaxNewSizePercent (Give more heap space to new objects) which also helped.

Answer (score 0):

I closed the connection and database object, created a new object database with the same parameters and a new connection, and finally called garbage collection.

Repeat the process as you need. I make a counter to repeat the process when I fill the half of my computer's memory.

Now I can run without errors.